# Java - Running Total in Simple GUI Banking Program

Tags: java, swing

I am having trouble trying to figure out how to code the deposits and withdrawals for my banking program and keep a running total. The program should start you with $0 in the bank and cannot go below $0. You are able to deposit and withdraw from this account and you can view who deposited and withdrew from the menu.

I need help trying to code the part that keeps the total of the account so that the user can't withdraw more than whats in the account. So if there is $100 in the account, they can't withdraw $200.

Note: The 'Create Account' action is just used to give yourself a unique ID when depositing/withdrawing and doesn't effect the login at all.

**Login.java:**

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Login {

    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private JLabel headerLabel;
    private JLabel statusLabel;
    private JPanel controlPanel;

    int cid;

    public Login() {
        prepareGUI();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Login login = new Login();
        login.showTextField();
    }

    private void prepareGUI() {
        mainFrame = new JFrame("Login");
        mainFrame.setSize(400, 400);
        mainFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
        mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent wE) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        headerLabel = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);
        statusLabel = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);

        statusLabel.setSize(350, 100);

        controlPanel = new JPanel();
        controlPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        mainFrame.add(headerLabel);
        mainFrame.add(controlPanel);
        mainFrame.add(statusLabel);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void showTextField() {
        headerLabel.setText("Account Access");

        JLabel namelabel = new JLabel("User ID: ", JLabel.RIGHT);
        JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password: ", JLabel.CENTER);
        final JTextField userText = new JTextField(6);
        final JPasswordField passwordText = new JPasswordField(6);

        JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");
        JButton createAccountButton = new JButton("Create Account?");

        loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                /*
                 * check for correct password/usernameinclude a desired
                 * 'hardcoded' username /password to verify againstuser input
                 * values for both username & password fieldsgive popup message
                 * if either username or password is incorrect
                 */
                if (userText.getText().equals("mister")
                        && passwordText.getText().equals("jim")) {

                    // close of Login window
                    mainFrame.dispose();
                    // open up MainWindow
                    new MainWindow(userText.getText(), cid);

                }

                else {
                    String message = "Incorrect username and/or password!\nTry again!";
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
                }
            }

        });

        createAccountButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                        "Enter your name");
                // generate client id
                Random r = new Random();
                cid = r.nextInt(100000);
            }

        });

        controlPanel.add(namelabel);
        controlPanel.add(userText);
        controlPanel.add(passwordLabel);
        controlPanel.add(passwordText);
        controlPanel.add(loginButton);
        controlPanel.add(createAccountButton);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.java:**

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class MainWindow extends JFrame {

    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private JLabel statusLabel;

    private JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
    private JMenu Account = new JMenu("Account");

    int cid;

    public MainWindow(String name, final int cid) {

        this.cid = cid;

        file.setMnemonic('F');
        JMenuItem ItemNew = new JMenuItem("New");
        ItemNew.setMnemonic('N');
        file.add(ItemNew);
        JMenuItem ItemExit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        ItemExit.setMnemonic('x');
        file.add(ItemExit);

        ItemExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        Account.setMnemonic('A');
        JMenuItem ItemDeposits = new JMenuItem("Deposits");
        ItemDeposits.setMnemonic('D');
        Account.add(ItemDeposits);

        JMenuItem ItemWithdraws = new JMenuItem("Withdrawals");
        ItemWithdraws.setMnemonic('W');
        Account.add(ItemWithdraws);

        JMenuItem ItemView = new JMenuItem("View Account");
        ItemView.setMnemonic('W');
        Account.add(ItemView);

        ItemDeposits.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {// add a deposit
                Double sBal = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                        null, "Enter deposit amount"));
                // create Account object
                Account accountObj = new Account();
                accountObj.setBal(sBal);

                // show result
                System.out.println(accountObj.getCID() + accountObj.getBal());
                File f = new File("account.dat");
                try {
                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f, true);
                    fw.write(cid + " " + accountObj.getBal() + "\n");

                    fw.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

        ItemWithdraws.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {// add a deposit
                Double sBal = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                        null, "Enter withdrawal amount"));
                // create Account object
                Account accountObj = new Account();
                accountObj.setBal(sBal);

                // show result
                System.out.println(accountObj.getBal());
                File f = new File("account.dat");
                try {
                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f, true);
                    fw.write(cid + " " + accountObj.getBal() + "\n");

                    fw.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

        ItemView.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                statusLabel.setVisible(false); // make status label invisible

                // set up JTable logic
                Vector<Vector<String>> myVector = new Vector<Vector<String>>(); // multidim
                                                                                // vector
                                                                                // (vector
                                                                                // of
                                                                                // vectors)

                try {

                    BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                            "account.dat"));
                    String input;
                    while ((input = file.readLine()) != null) {
                        String[] temp = input.split(" "); // grab row (record)
                                                            // data parsed by a
                                                            // space
                        Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>(); // single dim
                                                                    // vector to
                                                                    // get
                                                                    // fields in
                                                                    // each
                                                                    // record
                        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
                            v.add(temp[i]); // add each field to vector
                        }
                        myVector.add(v); // add all field data as a new vector
                                            // row (represents a record of data
                                            // each dynamically!!!)
                    }
                    file.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace(System.err);
                }

                Vector<String> columnData = new Vector<String>();
                columnData.addElement("ID");
                columnData.addElement("D/W");

                try {

                    JTable jt;

                    jt = new JTable(myVector, columnData);
                    jt.setBounds(30, 40, 200, 300);
                    JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(jt);

                    mainFrame.add(sp);

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println("There was a problem: " + ex);
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        ItemNew.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });
        statusLabel = new JLabel();

        statusLabel.setText("Currently Logged In: " + name + " #" + cid);
        statusLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
        statusLabel.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);

        prepareGUI();

    }

    private void prepareGUI() {
        mainFrame = new JFrame("Main");

        // adjust label position to sit in the upper right corner of window
        mainFrame.add(statusLabel);

        // add menu bar component to frame
        JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
        bar.add(file); // set menu orders
        bar.add(Account);
        mainFrame.setJMenuBar(bar);

        mainFrame.setSize(400, 400);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

**Account.java:**

```
public class Account {

    // data members
    double bal;
    static double intRate;
    int cid;
    String name;

    public Account() {
    }

    // getters
    double getBal() {
        return bal;
    }

    int getCID() {
        return cid;
    }

    // setters
    void setBal(double bal) {
        // update balance
        this.bal += bal;

    }

    void setCID(int cid) {
        this.cid = cid;
    }

    static void adjustIntRate(double r) {
        intRate = r;
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you need to provide more concrete problem description. What is it you are actually having a problem with?

Comment: Okay sorry I'll try to explain better.
I have this bank account with $0 and the program should keep a running total in the background so that when I try to withdraw from the account, it does not go under $0.

Comment: Well at the moment, there doesn't seem to be a way to decrease the balance in `Account`. Your withdrawl code seems to call the method that can only add to the balance.

Comment: setBal does not set the balance. It adds to the balance. It should be named something that reflects this.

Comment: No, you can pass a negative number to setBal (I think, I'll be honest I haven't compiled) which will decrease the balance.  If so, you just need an if statement in there.

Comment: Way too much code for such a simple question. How about creating from scratch a simple code sample that demonstrates your problem? Also, you don't specify if someone tries to withdraw more than they have, should it not do anything or should it set the amount in the account to 0?

Answer (score 0):

> I need help trying to code the part that keeps the total of the account so that the user can't withdraw more than whats in the account. So if there is $100 in the account, they can't withdraw $200.

Although you make no effort to explain this, I suppose `setBal` is what you use to withdraw and deposit. I also assume that a negative value passed to this method means withdrawal.

If you want to completely block a withdraw request for more than what you have, use:

```
void setBal(double bal) {

    if (this.bal + bal >= 0)
        this.bal += bal;
}
```

Meaning, "if withdrawing the amount leaves you at 0 or more, proceed (otherwise ignore)".

If you want to allow to withdraw the maximum amount that sets you to 0, use:

```
void setBal(double bal) {

    if (this.bal + bal >= 0)
        this.bal += bal;
    else
        this.bal = 0;
}
```

Meaning, "if withdrawing the amount leaves you at 0 or more, otherwise you are left with 0".